# How to implement dynamic array without pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I was told that you should avoid using pointers or new in c++ but I could not figure out how. I implemented dynamic array with iterator class. Here is the code:

Custom vector and iterator:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> class Myvector{

    private:
        int size;
        int capacity;
        T* objects;
        void add_capacity(){
            int newCapacity = capacity * 2 +1;
            T *newArray = new T[ newCapacity ];
            for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )         
                newArray[ i ] = std::move( objects[ i ] );
            capacity = newCapacity;
            std::swap( objects, newArray );  
            delete [ ] newArray;    
        }

    public:
        Myvector(){
            objects = new T[1];
            capacity = 1;
            size = 0;
        }

        void add(T obj){
            if (capacity == size){
                add_capacity();
            }
            objects[size] = obj;
            size += 1;
        }

        class Iterator
        {
            public:
                T* operator->() { return ptr; }
                Iterator(T *p) { 
                    ptr= p;
                }

                Iterator operator++() {
                    ++ptr; 
                    return *this;
                }
                bool operator!=(const Iterator & other) const{return ptr != other.ptr;}
                const T & operator*() const{return *ptr;}
            

            private:
                T * ptr; // Pointer to v.
        };

        Iterator begin() { 
            //return &objects[0];
            return Iterator(&objects[0]); 
        }
        Iterator end(){ 
            //return &objects[size];
            return Iterator(&objects[size]);
        }

};
```

So the question is that is is possible to implement this without pointers or new? I want to get better in c++.

Comment: You don't need to, C++ has [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The guideline is not to use new/delete outside datastructures. And pointers are fine as long as they are non-owning. If you need to allocate memory then use std::make_unique and use [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for your pointers

Comment: Also : a lot of pointers can be avoided by either using references (so you promise the objects pointed to are always valid). And then there is move semantics wich is another good technique to transfer ownership without pointers. So I think you should read the guideline as : when you want to type new/delete or use (naked) pointers... see if there isn't another way to do it (that is not too complicated).

Comment: If you are implementing a class from scratch to manage a dynamically allocated array, then you will (except in rather specialised or arcane use cases) probably fall back to using pointers and `new`/`delete` expressions.  However, the guideline of avoiding pointers and `new`/`delete` is premised on using capabilities from the C++ standard library such as containers (e.g. `std::vector`), smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) and related helper functions. The implementation of *those* capabilities will probably use pointers and `new`/`delete` by default, but *you* don't need to.

Comment: Dynamically allocating memory returns the location of the allocated memory.  Where are you going to store this address or location without using a pointer or iterator?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Inside a class, hidden behind an api. Look at std::vector, say std::vector<int> you dont access the dynamically allocated memory directly but you can use iterators and indices. No pointers required to access the integers. That is what this  guideline is about.  Leave memory allocation/managment to library builders and as a developer use those libraries. (library builders/developers are roles, you can be both of them)

Comment: @Peter the vast majority of the C++ standard library, including containers like vector, does NOT use `new`, but instead uses allocators.  I think `std::allocator` and the smart pointers are the only things that use `new`. (Excluding placement-new, which is an entirely different thing)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, the `std::vector` uses pointers, in one form or another.  The question still stands, where is the location of the dynamic memory stored if not using pointers?

Comment: Where the memory is stored depedens on the allocater being used by vector.  And vector does have pointers (in)to that memory.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yeah, I know that.   But this question is obviously asked by a beginner.    I doubt a beginner will benefit from the nuance that standard containers use an allocator and the default allocator they use, in turn, uses `new`.   The point for beginners is "use facilities from the standard library".    They don't really need to use non-default allocators, let alone roll their own allocators, in their first few weeks of learning C++.  That (if they ever need it) comes later.

Comment: I 100% agree, but the answer originally stated that vector used new, which wasn't technically true.

Answer (score 7):

What you heard is true. You should avoid raw owning pointers and `new` whenver possible.

Just don't miss the last part: "whenever possible". Raw owning pointers and `new` are not completely banned. They are tools that have their applications. Using an array with dynamic size is not one of them. There is `std::vector`. Use it.

Whenever you think you need to use `new` and a raw owning pointer you should revisit [`<memory>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) for smart pointers and the [containers library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). It is rare to not find what you need in there. And if you don't you will use a third party library rather than implementing your own container.

---

However, if we are talking about reimplementing `std::vector` (which you wouldn't do usually, but lets say you did), then things are different.

If you look at implementation of `std::vector` you will find that it does use raw pointers. The point is that this usage of raw pointers is encapsulated. `std::vector` grants you access to a pointer to the underlying array, but you never have to worry about calling `delete` on that pointer.

Your `MyVector` fails to manage ownership of the data it allocates. It has no destructor, it cannot be copied and it has more issues. If you do write a class that manages a ressource (can be a raw owning pointer, can be something else) you need to read about the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Though, what you should follow whenever possible is the rule of 0 (at the end of the linked article).

This last suggestion, "prefer rule of 0", is basically just "prefer container and smart pointer" for class members. Both "rules" help you to write simpler code. Code that has on average less bugs. You *can* choose to not follow the suggestion, but then you are on your own. Then you must take care to correctly manage the resources. And if you fail to do so you will be in trouble.

Comment: Ideally, even a custom container would use an allocator rather than using `new` and `delete` to directly allocate memory.

Comment: @MooingDuck if you intend for it to be allocator aware. There's some amount of YAGNI with allocators

Comment: @MooingDuck there was "..s and very likely it also uses new." which I removed. Not sure if you refer to that.